# Дублирование строк при выборке из FoxPro с использованием left join

Tags: delphi, база-данных

При выборке из таблиц foxpro с использованием left join получаю дубли записей. Программа написана на delphi, для подключения использую TADOQuery.

```
Исходные данные:
=====================
Имеем следующие таблицы: Люди, Страны, Города.
=====================
Поля в таблицах: 
Люди: Фамилия(varchar 100), Имя(varchar 100), Отчество(varchar 100), КодСтраны(int 11), КодГорода(int 11)
Страны: КодСтраны(int 11), Страна(varchar 100)
Города: КодГорода(int 11), Город(varchar 100)
=====================
Данные:

Люди:
Иванов, Андрей, Владимирович, 1, 2
Петров, Игорь, Юрьевич, 2, 1
Смирнов, Илья, Батькович, 2, 2

Страны:
1, Россия
2, НеРоссия

Города:
1, Город
2, пгт
======================
При выборке
select Люди.*, Страны.Страна, Города.Город from Люди
left join Страны on Люди.КодСтраны = Страны.КодСтраны
left join Города on Люди.КодГорода = Города.КодГорода

Получаем результат:
Иванов, Андрей, Владимирович, Россия, пгт
Иванов, Андрей, Владимирович, НеРоссия, пгт
Петров, Игорь, Юрьевич, НеРоссия, Город
Петров, Игорь, Юрьевич, Россия, пгт
Смирнов, Илья, Батькович, НеРоссия, пгт
Смирнов, Илья, Батькович, Россия, пгт
=======================
```

И чем больше таблиц мы подключаем, тем больше дублей получаем на выходе. Проявляется такая проблема только после "скрещивания" более двух таблиц.

Как избежать повторений?

Comment: А вы сделайте вывод всех полей и посмотрите почему лишние записи добавляются. У вас может некоторые страны один и тот же id имеют, или люди добавлены несколько раз. Или вы привели набор данных, на котором эта ошибка у вас точно воспроизводится и никаких других данных в таблицах нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо большое! Всему виной "Collating Sequence" компонента TADOQuery. После смены значения с "RUSSIAN" на "MACHINE" выборка начала правильно выполняться. Связано это с тем, что при "Collating Sequence=RUSSIAN" не учитывается регистр букв => Как заметил @ВОРОН , некоторые записи, ID которых содержат буквы (например 1b и 1B) считаются одинаковыми => Так я и получал дубли.